# How to create a static library from an Xcode project?

Tags: iphone

I struggling with a problem. I am having two apps. I want to link/integrate those two apps to my third app. I need to keep all these three apps class files and other resource files independent. Because most of them have the same name. How can I do this? I have to convert them to library and integrate them? If so, how to do that? Is there any other way to do it?..

I am having all these three apps as Xcode projects. I want only one app as the result after integrating..

I read in few forums that this is possible to do using static libraries. Can you suggest me the best way to create a static library from an existing Xcode project?

Any help pls..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your code and rename your classes,
using XCode's refactoring feature of course.