# Converting xcode project to static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries

Is there any way to convert a xcode project to  static library and use it in other project ? I have a project which reads QRcode it have its own static libraries  i want to make the whole project as a single library .

Comment: did you check http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a static library from an Xcode project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624604/how-to-create-a-static-library-from-an-xcode-project)

Comment: but it tells to create a new project i dont want to do that i just want to convert existing project to static library

Comment: you add this project in your wanted project

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do this? I'm having the same problem, and I think the way is to create a new target so that I can build my project into a static lib, but I'm still not able to do it right.

Comment: Any success on this? Looking for the same thing - converting an existing project into library (like in android)

Answer (score -1):

[The tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) tell you how to create a static library step by step.

You can add a new target(static lib) in your project and config the build phase of it.

Comment: but it tells to create a new project i dont want to do that i just want to convert existing project to static library